# $\lim\limits_{x\to0}{\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^2}}$ without L'Hopital

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

How do I compute this limit $$\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^2}}$$ without using L'Hopital.

Comment: power series of $e^x$?

Comment: What techniques are you allowed to use? (Or did you make this question up out of intellectual curiosity?)

Comment: Well I can use power series of $e^x$. (I'm going to try it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set $1/x^2=t$, the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}te^{-t}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t}{e^t}
$$
Now $e^t=1+t+t^2/2+\dots>1+t+t^2/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to prove by induction on the degree that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}P(1/x)e^{-1/x^2} = 0
$$
for all polynomials $P$ with $P(0)=0$.